# Can't fetch a geolocation result from imported MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, geolocation

I've downloaded Software77's [free geoip country DB](http://software77.net/geo-ip/). I've imported it using Sequel Pro - the resulting table looks to have the same amount of lines as in the .csv.

The following queries however, return 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM s77_country WHERE ip_num_start = "3000762368";
SELECT country_code FROM s77_country WHERE 3000831958 BETWEEN ip_num_start AND ip_num_end
```

In the .csv, line 49046:

```
"3000762368","3001024511","ripencc","1269993600","RS","SRB","Serbia"
```

That looks to be in the range, so the result should have been "RS".

Here's the table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `s77_country` (
  `ip_num_start` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_num_end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registry` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code_long` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are **missing semicolon** at the end of each statement. try using it.

Comment: I have omitted the semicolon in my question by mistake. The query returns null even with it.

Comment: ip_num does not fit in signed int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `BIGINT` or `int unsigned` for your IP_NUM. IP num value goes above 2b, INT is limited there

your maximum value for IP_NUM is theoretically 255*256^3+255*256^2+255*256+255 which is 4294967295, double of what signed int can store

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

edit: int unsigned fits exactly that value

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have missed one phase of error.

The value **`3000831958`** doesn't fit into the range of `int`. Use `bigint(11)` or `int(11) unsigned` instead both for `ip_num_start` and `ip_num_end`.

The record you have specified will not even be inserted into the table because of the range violation.

### Your select query is fine.

Comment: unsigned int is sufficient actually, read my answer from 10min ago